# How would you write the following set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to get started on this question:

Let $A = \{a:a = 3^n, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$

Let $B$ be defined as follows:

1. $3 \in B$, and
2. for any int $b$ and $c$, if $b \in B$ and $c \in B$, then $bc \in B$.

Then prove that $A$ is a subset of $B$, but that's not what I am worried about.

What does this set look like? My interpretation is $\{3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 2187, \dots\}$.

Does that seem correct?

Comment: Yes, that interpretation is correct.  The recursive definition of $B$ does make the mathematical notation somewhat difficult, but I think you have the answer...

Comment: $B$ is not defined as any one set, unless you specify that other than for those elements implied these three conditions, nothing else is in the set.

Comment: you missed $A \ni 729 = 3^6 = 3\times3\times3^2\times3^2 \in B$

Comment: I think I found another problem with this. We consider Z+ to include zero in class, and $3^0 = 1$, so how could $A \subset B$?

Comment: @SolidSnackDrive: I do not consider $0 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and neither does wolfram: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Plus.html 
$\mathbb{Z}^*$ on the other hand does include zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have enough definition to show *entirely* what $B$ may be, you only know two facts about *some of* its contents.   $3\in B$ and $\forall b\in\Bbb Z~\forall c\in\Bbb Z: ((b\in B\wedge c\in B)\to bc\in B)$.

That is enough that you *can* use a *proof by induction* to demonstrate that $B$ will at least contain a *certain subset* of the integers ; perhaps other elements, but at least all of those.   What is this subset?

---

> Hint: for all positive natural $n$, $3^n$ is an integer (and *also* an element of $A$).

Comment: What might an induction hypothesis look like for this? Is weak induction sufficient, or should I use strong?

Comment: Weak induction is suffient.  The base and iterative cases are readily obtained from the facts, the hint, and that you want to show $\forall a\in A~(a\in B)$ which is to say $\forall n\in \Bbb N^+~(3^n\in B)$.

Answer (score 2):

B is not defined.  You require B to have a property.
Thus A subset B.  N also has that property.  B can
be any subset of N that includes A.

Exercise.  Show A is the smallest set with that property.

Comment: So since B is not defined beyond 3 being in it, and pretty much any integer b and c, does that mean B could contain any integer? Which naturally makes A a subset of B?

Comment: "pretty much any integer b and c", is unacceptably vague.

Answer (score 0):

$B$ has to include all of $A$.  $3$ is in it and if $b$ is in it so is $3b$ so all powers of $3$ are in it.  That means that all of $A$ is in it.  There is nothing in the definition of $B$ that says other things are not in it.  The positive or nonnegative integers satisfy the definition, as do the reals, etc.